# Misunderstanding implicit rules with % in makefiles

Tags: makefile

So I am trying to use makefiles.
In the sequence of subsequent makefiles, I have one with the following code:

```
flash: $(TARGET).hex 
    $(AVRDUDE) $(AVRDUDE_MCU) $(AVRDUDE_OPTIONS) $(AVRDUDE_PORT) $(AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER) -U flash:w:$<

### Compilation rules
#Use all standard contiki compile rules, except add .elf rule that prints size
%.elf: %.$(TARGET)
    cp $< $@
    $(ELF_SIZE) $@

#Prepare images from ELF
%.fuses.bin: %.$(TARGET)
    $(OBJCOPY) $< -j .fuse -O binary --change-section-lma .fuse=0 $@

%.eep: %.$(TARGET)
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom="alloc,load" \
    --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O ihex $^ $@

%.hex: %.$(TARGET)
    $(OBJCOPY) $^ -j .text -j .data -j .bootloader -O ihex $@
```

When, from another makefile, doing "make cerberos" to make my project, it defines all the $(xxx) and includes all needed makefiles and calls "make flash" somewhere.

This fails with the following message:

```
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sven/git/cerberos/CerberOS/uJ/build/buildenv_java'
make flash
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sven/git/cerberos/CerberOS/uJ/build'
Building as uPNP Platform
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/sven/git/cerberos/CerberOS/UPNP/contiki/.git'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'avr-micropnp.hex', needed by 'flash'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sven/git/cerberos/CerberOS/uJ/build'
Makefile:113: recipe for target 'cerberos' failed
make: *** [cerberos] Error 2
```

And I don't understand why.
According to the gnu manual: "Thus, a pattern rule ‘%.o : %.c’ says how to make any file stem.o from another file stem.c."
So shouldn't the rule "%.hex: %.$(TARGET) ..." be the rule to make target 'avr-micropnp.hex'?
What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be lots of different pattern rules to build a single target (consider how many different ways there are to build an object file!)  So, if GNU make needs to build a target it will go through all the pattern rules to see if they match.  If one doesn't match it's not an error: GNU make simply goes to the next one.  If none match, you get the error you see.

For a pattern rule to match, first the target has to match the pattern.  Second, all the prerequisites have to either exist, or be buildable using other rules.  Since you have a pattern rule where the target matches, if it's reporting that the rule doesn't match it must mean that one or more of the prerequisites don't exist and can't be built.

You don't say what the value of the `TARGET` variable is, but the prerequisite `avr-micropnp.$(TARGET)` apparently doesn't exist and can't be built.

If you can't figure out why, you can run make with the `-d` option.  It generates a ton of output but if you search through it you will find out why make ignores this pattern rule.

Comment: This helped me resolve my issue, thank you. Now bumped up against the next one!